# Why can't I multiply a decimal by an integer on python

Tags: python

I have been trying to make a height calculator that converts cm to feet, here is my code:

```
print "how tall are you (in cm)?"
cm = raw_input()
answer = cm*int(0.03280839)
print answer
```

I know it's pretty simple but I have only just started so any tips on what is wrong would be great.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of problem do you face? Any error messages?

Answer (score 10):

`cm` is a string. You need to convert *it* to an number (integer or float) first. (You don't want to convert your conversion factor to an integer, since the result would just be multiplying the height by 0.)

```
print "how tall are you (in cm)?"
cm = raw_input()
answer = int(cm)*0.03280839
print answer
```

---

This just might be me, but 0.03280839 didn't strike me as an obvious conversion factor, while 2.54 (cm/inches) was much more recognizable. You can let Python do the work of converting cm to feet for you--convert to inches first, then convert to fee--for more readable code:

```
answer = int(cm) * 2.54 / 12
```

Or better yet, define a constant to use in place of the "magic" number.

```
FEET_PER_CM = 2.54 / 12  # 2.54 cm/inch ÷ 12 in/foot
# ...
answer = int(cm) * FEET_PER_CM
```

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, when you use `raw_input()`, it would return you a string. So you have to convert it to integer using `int(cm)`

Secondly, `int(0.03280839)` would round the number and return `0`. Why are you using `int` on that? just cut down the `int` from there. So the finished code should be:

```py
print "how tall are you (in cm)?"
cm = raw_input()
answer = int(cm) * 0.03280839 # use int(cm) to convert the string to integer
print answer
```